# How to include a bar for "total" in a stacked bar chart for categorical variable in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, stacked-chart

I would like to include a bar for "total" in a stacked bar chart plotting a categorical variable. A simplified example of my problem looks like this:

I have 3 cities (London, Berlin, Vienna) and 2 Types of tourists. I can plot the share of tourists that come more than once (repeat) versus those who come only once (once) for each city using the code below.

Now, I would like to add a bar for the share repeat/once in general (not by city) in the same chart. Unfortunately, I could not find any hint on how to do this.

I would be really grateful for a hint how to add this "total bar" as I need it quite frequently. Thank you very much in advance!

```
df <- data.frame("City"=c("Vienna","Vienna","London","London","Berlin", "London", "Berlin","Berlin","Vienna","Vienna","Vienna", "Vienna", "Berlin","Vienna","Vienna","Vienna"),"Type"=c("repeat","once","repeat","once","repeat","once", "repeat","once","repeat","once","repeat","repeat","repeat","repeat","repeat","once"))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=City, fill=Type), reorder(Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", alpha=0.75) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  coord_flip()


´´´
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by adding a second `geom_bar` where you map a constant (e.g. the string `Total`) on `x` and setting the order of categoreis via `scale_x_discrete`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=City, fill=Type), reorder(Type)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", alpha=0.75) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = "Total"), position="fill", alpha=0.75) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Total", unique(df$City))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! This works prefectly! (It also produces a bar for NA´s, even, if I drop them frist with df %>% drop_na(City) %>% , but I can work around this by producing a new data frame just for the chart with no NA´s.).

Comment: how do you specify what values you want to input for the total?  since "total" is not already a value in the dataframe

Comment: @BrendaThompson `geom_bar` automatically computes the count for the total category. Under the hood, by using `x="Total"` the `City` column aka the column mapped on `x` gets assigned a value of `Total` for each observation and hence we get the total count.

Comment: instead of count being a percentage, if count showed instead the actual counts of visitors (ex 10 for berlin, 5 for london, etc), how could we modify this to add the total count in another bar?

Comment: @BrendaThompson If you want to display the counts then drop `position=fill`.