# How can I add a bar with total count of values in ggplot clustered bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the following data:

```
df <- data.frame("City"=c("Vienna","Vienna","London","London","Berlin", "London", "Berlin","Berlin","Vienna","Vienna","Vienna", "Vienna", "Berlin","Vienna","Vienna","Vienna"),"Type"=c("repeat","once","repeat","once","repeat","once", "repeat","once","repeat","once","repeat","repeat","repeat","repeat","repeat","once"),"Cases"=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,10,20,30,40,50,60,40))
```

I can create a clustered bar chart showing counts of various values:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Type, x=City,y=Cases))+
geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")
```

but I can't figure out how to add a bar that has the total case count across all x variables (City) and filled according to Type.

ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can summarize the data frame then bind it to the original:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  summarize(Cases = sum(Cases), .by = c("Type")) %>% 
  mutate(City = "All", .before = "Type") %>%
  bind_rows(summarize(df, Cases = sum(Cases), .by = c("City", "Type"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(City, Cases, fill = Type)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically this could be achieved the same way as in my previous answer on [How to include a bar for "total" in a stacked bar chart for categorical variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71498626/12993861). However, in our case we have to compute the sum of the variable mapped on `y` for which  we could or have to switch to `stat_summary` with `fun = sum`. Actually, we have to use `stat_summary` for the individual bars too as there are multiple observations per city in the data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(fill = Type, x = City, y = Cases)) +
  stat_summary(fun = sum, geom = "col", position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(aes(x = "Total"), fun = sum, geom = "col", position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Total", unique(df$City)))
```

[image]

Comment: lol, different approaches, same result, within a few seconds

Comment: @AllanCameron Yeah. Have to confess though that I had a small advantage as the question is based on one of my previous answers and I already exchanged some comments with the OP. For that reason I decided to go for `stat_summary` to show how my former approach could be adapted to this case. But in the end I think using some data wrangling is the easier approach to tackle the issue. (;